# Append to a php directive rather than replace?

Tags: php, configuration, ubuntu

I installed the zendframework package on my ubuntu box, and noticed that it added a new ini file at `/etc/php5/conf.d/zend.ini` with the following:

```
[Zend]
; include_path=${include_path} ':/usr/share/php/Zend'
```

When I enable the directive in this file I would expect the resulting include path to be:

```
.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear:/usr/share/php/Zend
```

However, all I get is:

```
 :/usr/share/php/Zend
```

When I disable the directive, get_include_path() reports:

```
.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear
```

Is this valid ini syntax? Why isn't it working?

I'm using PHP version 5.3.2 on Ubuntu 10.04 (last build update May 3rd 2011). It would be great if I could do this, as it keeps the configuration system nice and modular.

Comment: yes whats its showing is valid. Its added all the zend releated file in include path.

Comment: @pradeep thanks - I think I wasn't too clear with the question, so I've edited it a bit to point out that it is not working as expected.

Comment: see wht the variable 'include_path' reads in php.ini file.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely that `${include_path}` doesn't contain anything. Check your php.ini for include_path and add your include paths from there.